# Unable to change geolocation through VPN is it advisable to consider changing the IP address?

Tags: vpn, web

**Unable to change geolocation through VPN; is it advisable to consider changing the IP address?**

Lately, I've been experiencing difficulties in altering my geolocation through a VPN. I use a [NordVPN](https://nordvpn.com/download/windows/) service, but the geographical location remains unchanged. I am exploring the possibility that the issue might be related to the IP address. I've conducted some research on forums but haven't found a clear solution yet.

I've attempted to change the location through various VPN services and checked geolocation settings in the browser, but the changes aren't taking effect. Considering the potential impact of the IP address, I'm open to suggestions or recommendations to address this issue.

Comment: I suspect your VPN provider does not have unique servers by location. If you are using VPN, do you see the VPN server location if you visit https://www.ip2location.io?